# Selecting features from shapefile where field="value" using Geopandas?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, geopandas

I don't understand the difference between OGR and Geopandas librairies. 
I have checked the documentation of GDAL as well as http://geopandas.org/ but I still don't get it.
I just started learning about them and for now I'm trying to write some scripts in python using Geopandas.

My goal is to select features from a shapefile where field="value", then export the selected features to a shapefile.
The second step would be to add another field to the output shapefile(with only the selected features from the first shapefile) and set it to a certain value.
Doing the second part with OGR seems easy. This is how I've done it :

```
from osgeo import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSrc = driver.Open("myshp.shp", 1)
fld = ogr.FieldDefn('City', ogr.OFTString)
lyr = dataSrc.GetLayer()
lyr.CreateField(fld)
for feature in lyr:
    feature.SetField("Not Found", fld)
    layer.SetFeature(feature)
dataSrc= None
```

However I don't see how I can do the same thing using Geopandas. I might be missing the point though that's why I'm confused between the use of the two librairies.

I know that this is easily done using QGIS or ArcGIS manually, but as of now I'm trying to learn how to use python with Geopandas.

How can I achieve my goal explained above using Geopandas?

Comment: I think you should focus your question on how to achieve that one specific goal instead of asking a broad question about differences.

Comment: @PolyGeo My main concern is to know the use of each library and therefore the difference between them. By knowing that I might know if that goal is achievable in the first place or not.
I don't know how specific I can be?

Comment: I've edited to show how.  It now asks a single specific question rather than two questions (one specific and one broad).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't knew geopandas, it is very easy to add a field, a great library indeed. You just need to read your file add it and save.

```
dataSrc = gpd.read_file('my_shp.shp')
dataSrc['new_field'] = 1
dataSrc.to_file('newfile.shp')
```

Selecting is also straightforward:

```
dataSrc = gpd.read_file('my_shp.shp')
dataSrc[dataSrc['id']<4].to_file('new_shape.shp')
```

Comment: Thank u so much @caiohamamura! It works. 
I am still confused though about the use of OGR and Geopandas. Can u clarify this point for me please?

Comment: They are just different libraries, as I said I don't know geopandas, looks like a new library (version is still 0.2). OGR is very mature. I think geopandas still won't have many options to access things OGR already does, but for what I've already seen geopandas is FAR easier. But usually there's a tradeoff between easy and access to advanced features.

Comment: Also another difference is that OGR is directly wrapped to C++ OGR libraries, while geopandas uses other python libraries such as fiona which uses OGR wrapper, so you have many layers between python code and C++ code, this usually will lead to worse performance.